# Set ng-model to value value in scope?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a simple angular app with two controllers:

```
function Invite($scope) {
$scope.fieldsets =
    [
        {
        fields:
            [
                {
                    label: 'First Name',
                    name: 'firstname',
                    key: 'entry.810220554',
                    type: 'text',
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Last Name',
                    name: 'lastname',
                    key: 'entry.1653030831',
                    required: true,
                },
                {
                    label: 'Email',
                    name: 'email',
                    key: 'entry.1727688842',
                    required: true,
                    type: 'email',
                },
                {
                    key: 'entry.1602323871',
                    type: 'radio',
                    labels:
                    [
                        {
                            name: 'media',
                            label: 'Media'
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'frilans',
                            label: 'Frilans'
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
    ];
}

function Questionnaire($scope, $http){
    $scope.post = function(){
        console.log();
        $http.post('/signup.php', $scope.quiz).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
 }
```

The Questionare-scope is a child of the invite scope. Here is simplified version of the layout

```
<div ng-controller="Invite">
   <form ng-controller="Questionnaire" method="POST" ng-submit="post()">
     <input ng-model="{{field.key}}" />
   </form>
</div>
```

The first one generates a form where I want the key-values to be used as ng-model.
In the second scope, so that I can post them to the server with that key.

I first tried to use

```
 <input ng-model="{{field.key}}" />
```

in my html template, this was my intuitive guess, but it rendered an error.

```
 <input ng-model="field.key" />
```

this also giving error.

Here is a plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/rnQXlCCFQypVLs20OuTt?p=preview

Comment: try  <input ng-model="{{fields.key}}" />

Comment: Sorry, i didn't include that in my template there is a ng-repeat="field in fields"

Comment: can u create a plunker for your code http://plnkr.co/ Would be easy to debug your code

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rnQXlCCFQypVLs20OuTt?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

There is no object `fields` in the questionnaire scope.  You may be able to reference the object to in the outer scope by using `ng-repeat=field in $parent.fields`, I'm not sure if nested scopes are related via prototypical inheritance.

Another approach would be to create a service that tracks fields and inject it into all the controllers that need access to the data.

Comment: As fields are inherited from parent to child, I can use the fields-object inside the child-scope, the problem is that I want to use the value of the parent scope to set the key of the child scope.

Comment: I see, well, the field item being displayed is a copy of an item in the field array.  I think you need to use a service to share data between controllers.  Why are you nesting the controllers?  What benefit does the questionnaire controller provide?

Comment: The outercontroller is basically an controller that generates most of the html, I have cut out part of the scope in this question, because it isn't relevant. The Questionnare-controller is used to save data to the server. I could put it all in one controller, this won't help howver, I asked a more general question, for the same problem, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896732/use-value-in-scope-to-name-ng-model