# Use value in Scope to name ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

Assume I have an object that looks like this:

```
$scope.obj.foo = 'bar';
```

I want an input-field to have the ng-model='bar'

If I define it like this:

```
<input ng-model="{{obj.foo}}" />
```

I get a javascript error

If I define it like this:

```
<input ng-model="obj.foo" />
```

the ng-model is obj.foo and the input-element get's populated with the value bar.

How should I write my template in order to achieve an input-field that works like this:
Desired outcome:

```
<input ng-model="bar" />
```

but fetching the ng-model-name from the scope rather than writing it into the template.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Updated my question now to clarify!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an object anyway for the model, so you can do like this

```
<input ng-model="obj[myModelName]" />
```

and then plug in the `myModelName` with either `"foo"` or `"bar"`.